# Performance com multipart/form-data

Tags: html

Independente da linguagem usada no lado servidor (php, asp, jsf, etc), existe algum problema em adicionar o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` mesmo em formulários de páginas que **não** fazem upload de arquivo?

Porque uso modelo (template) numa aplicação e a tag do formulário fica no template. Como somente algumas páginas fazem upload, o atributo constará em todas as páginas, mesmo as que não fazem upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com [essa pergunta no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean), existem três valores que você pode passar no enctype:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (padrão)
- `multipart/form-data`
- `text/plain`

A regra geral é: se você estiver fazendo upload de arquivos, use `multipart/form-data`; senão, use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Nunca use `text/plain`.

Respondendo a sua pergunta: quando você não anexa nenhum tipo de arquivo no seu formulário, acredito que o melhor seja usar `multipart/form-data`. Esse formato usa menos bytes do que o `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Portanto, o processamento no lado do servidor também deve ser menor por estar manipulando uma cadeia de caracteres menor.

Comment: Realmente, fiz o teste com um formulário com dois campos nos dois modos. No `multipart/form-data` o content-length do post ficou bem maior. Acredito que o único problema então seja performance. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

O atributo `enctype` é responsável por definir como os dados do formulários serão codificados quando estes forem submetidos, e também só funciona com o `POST`.

Atualmente existem 3 valores que podem especificados nesse atributo:

- **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
- **multipart/form-data**
- **text/plain**

O `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` é o valor padrão para o `enctype` caso nenhuma seja especificado, e se estiver em uso, todos os caracteres são codificados antes de serem enviados.

Caso, seja definido o `multipart/form-data` como valor para esse atributo, nenhum caractere é codificado. Esse tipo de requisição contém várias partes, e cada parte dessa requisição contém um `content-diaposition` com o tipo `form-data`, e com um parâmetro adicional `name` cujo valor é o nome do campo.

Por último tem o `text/plain` que converte os espaços em `+`, porém não codifica nada.

[Segundo o RFC-2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) Cada parte de um `multipart/form-data` deve possuir um content type. Em casos onde o campo é um text, o conjunto de caracteres de entrada indicam qual será a codificação a usar.

> **RFC-2388 - 4.5 -**
>   Por exemplo, um formulário com um campo de texto em que um usuário digitou 'Joe deve
>    100 ", onde  é o símbolo do euro pode ter dados de formulários devolvidos Como:
>
> ```
> --AaB03x
> content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"
> content-type: text/plain;charset=windows-1250
> content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
> ```

**RFC-2388 - 5.2 -**
A codificação `multipart/form-data` tem alta sobrecarga e alguns impactos no desempenho caso haja demasiados campos com poucos valores. Mas em prática essa sobrecarga não é significativa. Se quiseres realmente mais detalhes, ou não for claro o suficiente, terás de ler este e alguns dos outros RFC, para melhor análise dos ganhos e das perdas. Outra boa fonte seria esta página [aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) da w3.

Answer (score -4):

Quando você esta fazendo um formulário, é necessário especificar o tipo de arquivo que você deseja fazer upload.

Por padrão, usa-se:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Mas não é isso que está sendo perguntado.